# Count number of rows after group by multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to count the number of rows by dplyr after group_by.
I have the following data:

```
   id  code Type
1   4   3.7    A
2   4   244    B
3   4   3.7    A
4   6     3    A
5   6    14    B
6   6    D5    A
7   8   563    B
8   8  75.1    B
9   8  75.1    B
```

I tried this :
 `df %>% group_by(c(id, code, Type)) %>% summarise(n = n())`

But got

```
Error in `group_by()`:
! Problem adding computed columns.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = c(id, code, Type)`.
✖ `..1` must be size 88765150 or 1, not 266295450.
```

I would like my output data to look something like this:

```
   id  code Type  n 
1   4   3.7    A  2
2   4   244    B  1
3   6     3    A  1
4   6    14    B  1
5   6    D5    A  1
6   8   563    B  1
7   8  75.1    B  2
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for all your assistance.

Comment: It isn't clear to me how the group sizes correspond to the values you indicate in your example output. Do you mean to bin the `code` variable into a factor so you aren't grouping by a continuous value? If not, the first row there looks like it should have a group size of 1.

Comment: @SGE, hi, I want group by 3 columns (id  code Type) then count how many time .

Comment: could you please share the original data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the `c()` in the `group_by()` command

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id, code, Type) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())
```

Or alternatively

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id, code, Type) %>% 
  count
```